# No table exists Pandasql update statement

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to run the following code:

```
pdsql('update table_x set var1 = 'foo' where var1='bar' ;')
```

I get an error messaging saying table_x does not exist. 
Which is odd because running

```
pdsql('select count(var1) from table_x;')
```

Works fine.

Any ideas or suggestions as to what's going on?